# What does 191767 mean in "Paper, Cardboard for Set 4336 #1, Scala Cat (191767)"

Tags: piece-information, bricklink

In BL http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4336cdb01
This cardboard's name is "Paper, Cardboard for Set 4336 #1, Scala Cat (191767)"

What does "(191767)" mean here in the description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an number printed on the piece of paper, so it's easy to identify and to search (if you look at the picture of the "part" you will see it).

If you were asking about the actual (internal) meeaning of the number then I don't know for sure, sorry. I assume it's just an identification code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Normally (like on brick parts) the number on it represents the parts' lego item ID. But the paper's item ID is not the number print on it, so its kind of strange.

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that it is the LEGO *element ID* (6-7 digits as far as my observation goes). This is different from the *item number* which is shown on the bricks or on BrickLink. The *item number* usually contains (or is equal to) the *design number*.

Example: I have a 2x6 plate in tan. This shows the number 3795. As this is a common piece I looked it up on the LEGO website (search by *design number*) and this reveals that the *element ID* (which also contains color information) is 4113993. Some element IDs contain the design number as well, e.g. **3795**01 is the very same plate in white.

Unfortunately the piece in question seems to be rather old, so I could not find any information about it online. (And to find element IDs is a challange by itself as they seem to be "LEGO internal".)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, and welcome to Bricks.SE!